# Get Sub Folder name dynamic

Tags: excel, vba

I have sub folders in the following directory:

```
D:\\NOSTRO\\DATA SOURCE\\June 21, 2023
```

What if I want to get the name of the last folder (June 21, 2023) but note that the name of the sub folder is dynamic or subject to change?

Comment: What do you mean with _last folder_? Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60483538/6600940) of any help? And please also check this [site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on asking

Comment: Is that "last subfolder" the single one on the path you show (I mean, in "DATA SOURCE")? Are there other **files** besides that "last folder"?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub test()
    Dim res As String
    res = Dir("D:\NOSTRO\DATA SOURCE\*", vbDirectory)
    Do While res <> ""
       If InStr(res, ",") = 0 Then
          Debug.Print res
       ElseIf Not IsNumeric(Right(res, 4)) Then
          Debug.Print res
       ElseIf InStr("Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec", _
                    Left(res, 3)) = 0 Then
          Debug.Print res
       Else
          ' A comma was found in the directory name
          ' It starts with a month and the last 4 digits are numeric
          ' probably the right pattern so do something with res
       End If
       res = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```